# Why the integer data types hexadecimal, octal and binary are getting converted to decimal type and then displayed in a browser?

Tags: php, types, type-conversion, integer, var-dump

I'm using PHP **7.1.11**

I've following PHP code :

```
<?php
$a = 0123; // an octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$b = 0x1A; // a hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
$c = 0b11111111; // a binary number (equivalent to 255 decimal)

var_dump($a); //Output : int(83) int(26) int(255) 
var_dump($b); //Output : int(26) int(255)
var_dump($c); //Output : int(255)
?>
```

My question is why the data contained in integer data types of octal, hexadecimal and binary are getting converted into decimal and then displayed in browser along with the new datatype **integer**?

Why it's not showing the original values of variables and also not showing their original data type?

Why there is a conversion step and who does this for what reason?

If we take other data types life boolean, float, string nothing like this happen. Everything works as expected then why this weird thing is happening with these integer data types?

Comment: Even an octal number is an integer, binary numbers are integers etc... There is no subtype - octal integer.  All it's doing is displaying the values you've created.

Comment: @NigelRen : Octal, Binary and Hexadecimal all are integers that I know but why they are getting converted to decimal integers and losing their original context of being octal, hexadecimal and binary? This is my question.

Comment: I updated my comment to say - there is no such thing as sub-types for integers, they are all represented internally in binary.  They are just being displayed in decimal as this is what most people want.

Comment: @NigelRen : Then what's the purpose of adding the notations to represent octal(0), hexadecimal(0x) and binary(b) to the PHP core as they are ultimately going to get convert into decimal?

Comment: It's a convenient way of allowing a programmer to use different number bases when setting data.  So if you are using (for example) file permissions in *nix - 0760 is much more meaningful than 496, though they are the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only one kind of (integer) number, and the format of the number is completely unimportant. The values `052`, `42` and `0x2A` all represent exactly the same value. PHP doesn't remember how a number was created; it doesn't store that information because it's useless information that would only waste space being stored. Binary, octal and hexadecimal notations are mere convenience affordances to allow you to express numbers in the most suited notation for the context; it's all being parsed to an `int` of the same value and then output in decimal notation by default.